# setValue in combox, still sends value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following code:

```
selectMainSector: function(component) {
    var typeSectorId = component.getValue(), mainCombobox = component.nextSibling();
    if (typeSectorId == 0) { //se o valor for 0 - setor
        mainCombobox.disable();
        mainCombobox.setValue('');
    }
    if (typeSectorId != 0) { //Se o valor for 1 - subsetor
        mainCombobox.enable();
    }
},
```

In this code I make a rule for when combobox is selected, it enables the next one and when it selects the other record it hides combobox again and clears the value. But if I edit the registry and select the value that hides and clears the other saved combobox, the value is still sent and saved. I think when I'm giving setValue, I'm not clearing the value that was saved before, so it still saves. How do I not save this value?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if (typeSectorId == 0) { //se o valor for 0 - setor
    mainCombobox.clearValue();
    mainCombobox.disable();
}
```

Comment: could you post more code? How are you saving the data?

Comment: I am using my crud, but I don't think that's it. Because I'm using it for others too

Comment: Try creating fiddle here https://fiddle.sencha.com/ where you reproduce your case and then post link back here

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```js
if (typeSectorId == 0) { //se o valor for 0 - setor
    mainCombobox.disable();
    mainCombobox.setValue(null);
}
```